# GCDでキューの優先度をつけたい

Tags: swift

グローバルのキューを使う場合、優先度が指定できますが、

```
dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)
DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH
DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT
DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_LOW
DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND
```

`dispatch_queue_create()`で作成したキューには優先度は指定できないのでしょうか。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dispatch_queue_create()`で作成したキューは、`DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT`で動作します。

この優先度を変える場合は、`dispatch_get_global_queue`で変更したい優先度のキューを取得して、`dispatch_set_target_queue`で指定します。

```
let queue = dispatch_queue_create("com.test", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL)
let targetPriorityQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_LOW, 0)
dispatch_set_target_queue(queue, targetPriorityQueue)
```

- 参考
  [Grand Central Dispatch (GCD) Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/dispatch_set_target_queue)

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます！
リファレンスをきちんと読めていませんでした。
大変勉強になりました。早速試してみたいと思います！